# How to select multiple values into an array and loop through? (postgres 9.3)

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, array

I have simple table for the sake of argument. I have a function that selects ids and loops through them called `loop_test`. I can select an array of ids and loop through them, causing my changes in a transaction.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION loop_test() RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
        _ids_array INTEGER[];
        _id INTEGER;
BEGIN
        SELECT ARRAY(SELECT id FROM loop_test) INTO _ids_array; 
        FOREACH _id IN ARRAY _ids_array
        LOOP
                UPDATE loop_test SET looped = TRUE WHERE id = _id;
        END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Table:

```
db=# \d loop_test;
      Table "public.loop_test"
    Column     |  Type   | Modifiers 
---------------+---------+-----------
 id            | integer | 
 other_id      | integer | 
 id_copy       | integer | 
 other_id_copy | integer | 
 looped        | boolean | 

db=# select * from loop_test;
 id | other_id | id_copy | other_id_copy | looped 
----+----------+---------+---------------+--------
  1 |       10 |         |               | 
  6 |       15 |         |               | 
  2 |       11 |         |               | 
  7 |       16 |         |               | 
  3 |       12 |         |               | 
  4 |       13 |         |               | 
  5 |       14 |         |               | 
(7 rows)
```

When I call `select loop_test()`, I get the following results:

```
db=# select * from loop_test;
 id | other_id | id_copy | other_id_copy | looped 
----+----------+---------+---------------+--------
  1 |       10 |         |               | t
  6 |       15 |         |               | t
  2 |       11 |         |               | t
  7 |       16 |         |               | t
  3 |       12 |         |               | t
  4 |       13 |         |               | t
  5 |       14 |         |               | t
(7 rows)
```

**I would, however, like to create a function to select both the `id` and the `other_id` into an array.** I was told about using something like `agg_array`, but I don't completely understand how that works.

I was imagining something like the following?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION agg_loop_test() RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
        _ids_array INTEGER[][];
        _id INTEGER;
BEGIN
        SELECT AGG_ARRAY(SELECT id, other_id FROM loop_test) INTO _ids_array;
        FOREACH _id IN ARRAY _ids_array
        LOOP
                UPDATE loop_test SET id_copy = _id[0], other_id_copy = _id[1] WHERE id = _id[0];
        END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Why are you using a loop at all?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A *much* better way, yet: just update. No loop needed.

```
UPDATE loop_test
SET    id_copy = id
     , other_id_copy = other_id;
WHERE  id IS NOT NULL;
```

The `WHERE` condition is only useful if `id` can be null and you want a perfect equivalent of what you had.

#### Loop

If you are just exploring loops - you can assign multiple variables. See:

- [SELECT INTO with more than one attribution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16311870/939860)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION better_loop_test()
  RETURNS void
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _id int;
   _other_id int;
BEGIN
   -- example makes no sense, just a loop demo
   FOR _id, _other_id IN
      SELECT id, other_id FROM loop_test
   LOOP
      UPDATE loop_test
      SET    id_copy = _id
           , other_id_copy = _other_id
      WHERE id = _id;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

While you just need the two columns of known type, that may be a bit cheaper than fetching whole (possibly big) rows.

Answer (score 2):

The @Erwin's reply is absolutely correct. Using a arrays for described example is performance error (unfortunately common). Sometimes it can be necessary - because you need to pass some values as function parameters.

There are two techniques - 1. pass a array of composite values, 2. pass multidimensional array. The performance should be +/- same, for me - using a array of composite can  be for some cases more readable. Not sure, if you can create multidimensional arrays from query result on 9.3.

```
CREATE TYPE test_type AS (id1 int, id2 int);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fx1(ids test_type[])
RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE r test_type;
FOR r IN ARRAY ids
LOOP
  UPDATE ...
END LOOP;
```

probably still, there can be used only one `UPDATE` statement without cycle with function `unnest`:

```
CREATE TABLE test (id1 integer, id2 integer);

UPDATE test SET id2 = u.id2 
  FROM unnest(array[(1,10),(3,4)]::test_type[]) u
 WHERE test.id1 = u.id1;
```

The performance impact depends on size of arrays - for small arrays it will be minimal - but still there can be deeper nesting of cycles, and there it can be performance issue.

For multidimensional [arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/plpgsql-control-structures.html) PLpgSQL `FOREACH` statement has `SLICE` clause:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fx2(ids int[])
RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE _ids int[];
BEGIN
  FOREACH _ids SLICE 1 IN ARRAY ids
  LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'ids[0]=% ids[1]=%', _ids[0], _ids[1];
  END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

postgres=# SELECT fx2(ARRAY[[1,2],[3,4]]);
NOTICE:  ids[0]=<NULL> ids[1]=1
NOTICE:  ids[0]=<NULL> ids[1]=3
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about multidimensional arrays, but I found a much better way to do what I was trying to do:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION better_loop_test() RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
        _row RECORD;
BEGIN
        FOR _row IN SELECT * FROM loop_test LOOP
                UPDATE loop_test SET id_copy = _row.id, other_id_copy = _row.other_id WHERE id = _row.id;
        END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```