# Function that loops through array parameter values to build multiple WHERE clauses (postgres 11.4)

Tags: postgresql, functions, array, postgresql-11, where

I have been iterating on an idea presented by Rob Conery in his [excellent post](https://rob.conery.io/2018/08/01/simple-monthly-reports-in-postgresql-using-generate_series/) to generate monthly reports using PostgreSQL Views.

My version required the View to be refactored into a Function as I needed to utilize input parameters. I recently received a request to add filtering so that specific products and locations could be searched as well, but I found myself executing this function N number of times, which caused a significant performance bottleneck. I figured having these conditions in one query would alleviate these performance issues.

I made a bit of progress after following the (very well-written) answers to some questions here, but I am still stuck wrapping my head around how to generate  `WHERE` clauses for each input array element.

Essentially my desired "output" SQL would look something like this:

```sql
select sum(total) as total_activity, 
  count(1) as sales_event_count,
  created_at::date as sales_event_date,
  date_part('year',created_at at time zone 'hst') as year,
  date_part('quarter',created_at at time zone 'hst') as quarter,
  date_part('month',created_at at time zone 'hst') as month,
  date_part('day',created_at at time zone 'hst') as day
from locations loc
left outer join sales_events se ON loc.id = se.location_id
left outer join junction_products jp ON jp.sales_event_id = se.id
left outer join products p ON p.id = jp.product_id
where (p.sku = '12345' and p.manufacturer = 'CompanyA' and location_id = 'LocationA') or 
      (p.sku = '09876' and p.manufacturer = 'CompanyA' and location_id = 'LocationA') or
      (p.sku = '10293' and p.manufacturer = 'CompanyB' and location_id = 'LocationA')
group by se.created_at
order by se.created_at
```

Here are some example pages that I have explored to help tackle this problem:

- [Pass multiple sets or arrays of values to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600567/pass-multiple-sets-or-arrays-of-values-to-a-function)
- [How to select multiple values into an array and loop through? (postgres 9.3)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/222297/how-to-select-multiple-values-into-an-array-and-loop-through-postgres-9-3)
- [Selecting from multidimensional array parameter in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29401365/selecting-from-multidimensional-array-parameter-in-postgres)

After picking and choosing from each of these, I have come up with the following:

```sql
create type product_type as(sku character varying(100), manufacturer character varying(200))

create or replace function find_sales_location_activity(
  _products_arr product_type[],
  _location_id bigint
)
returns table (total_activity bigint, sales_event_count bigint, sales_event_date date, "year" double precision, quarter double precision, "month" double precision, "day" double precision) as
$func$
select sum(total) as total_activity, 
  count(1) as sales_event_count,
  created_at::date as sales_event_date,
  date_part('year',created_at at time zone 'hst') as year,
  date_part('quarter',created_at at time zone 'hst') as quarter,
  date_part('month',created_at at time zone 'hst') as month,
  date_part('day',created_at at time zone 'hst') as day
from locations loc
left outer join sales_events se ON loc.id = se.location_id
left outer join junction_products jp ON jp.sales_event_id = se.id
left outer join products p ON p.id = jp.product_id
where (p.sku = $1[1][1] and p.manufacturer = $1[1][2] and location_id = $2) or 
      (p.sku = $1[2][1] and p.manufacturer = $1[2][2] and location_id = $2) or
      (p.sku = $1[3][1] and p.manufacturer = $1[3][2] and location_id = $2)
group by se.created_at
order by se.created_at
$func$
language sql;
```

...but obviously this isn't looping over anything. I have experimented with replacing the `FROM locations loc` clause with `FROM generate_subscripts($1, 1)` and attempting to loop through that way, but replacing the table name causes my `left outer join`'s to fail.

Clearly I'm a bit out of my depths here, but I'd really, really appreciate it if anyone could lead me in the right direction. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unrelated, but: `count(1)` is actually slower than `count(*)`

Comment: Good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters in the array may be transformed into a table
to be be joined against the rest. This transformation is
done with the `unnest` function and the WHERE conditions can then be expressed as
JOIN clauses.

This could also be done by joining with `generate_subscripts($1, 1)` but that leads to more complicated syntax for no apparent benefit.

```sql
select ...<same as your query>...
from locations loc
left outer join sales_events se ON loc.id = se.location_id
left outer join junction_products jp ON jp.sales_event_id = se.id
left outer join products p ON p.id = jp.product_id
join unnest($1) params ON (p.sku=params.sku AND p.manufacturer=params.manufacturer)
WHERE location_id = $2
group by se.created_at
order by se.created_at
```

Note: this query leaves the `left outer join` as they are in the original query because the question is not about them, but it seems they should be inner joins instead.
The reason is that WHERE clauses like  `p.sku = '12345' and p.manufacturer = 'CompanyA'`
imply that these columns in p cannot be NULL, but that negates the reason why you'd use an outer join versus an inner join, which is having NULL columns added for non-matching rows from each table at the right side of each left join.

In short, if you're not sure why this query uses `left outer join`, consider replacing them  with `join`.

Comment: Apologies for the delay but this was _precisely_ what I was looking for. Thank you so much for your help! The comments about my `left outer join` usage were also greatly appreciated.